# How much dodge do I get per point in Dexterity?

Tags: diablo-iii

For the first 100 points of Dexterity, it seems I get 0.1% chance to dodge per point. After that, however, it starts getting into decimal numbers and I can't figure out the exact equation.

What are the functions involved for figuring out how much dodge chance I will have given my Dexterity score?

Comment: As the author of the [doge2048] question, I greatly approve of this bounty message "typo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Diablo 3 RoS **Patch 2.1**, which was release on **8/26/2014**,

> **Dexterity no longer grants Dodge chance.**

A character can only get dodge chance from skills now.

Comment: You now get 1 armor per dexterity.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Click to Loot's combat guide](http://www.clicktoloot.com/p/combat.html#dodge):

```
Dex range    Dodge% per point of Dex
1 - 100      0.100
101 - 500    0.025
501 - 1000   0.020
1001 - 8000  0.010
```

So, for example, 600 dexterity gives `100*0.1 + 400*0.025 + 100*0.02 = 22%`

I was able to confirm these calculations myself on my high-dex character.

Comment: This is making me like the idea of my dodge monk even more :P

Comment: If your dex is over 1000, it's just %30 + (Dex - 1000) * 0.01%

Comment: I'm going to assume these calculations have changed with the addition of the expansion set. I have a DH with 4400 dexterity, and based on these numbers I should have 64% dodge chance. I have a 20.3% dodge chance.

Comment: So for me its not working, I've 77 dexterity and 0.35% dodge chance.
With your formula I get 7.7% dodge chance witch is wrong. 77*0.1=7.7%

Comment: @Rey This answer is outdated since 2.0. No one has answered with the new, correct answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

The Dodge Chance % shown under your character sheet details is derived directly from your Dexterity. The Dodge amount per dexterity point no longer varies based on how many points you have, rather by the level that you are:

At level 70, the relationship is:

> Dexterity / 217 = Dodge %, rounded to the nearest 0.X%

I have tested this from 77 to 8096 dexterity in 5 dexterity increments. This means to get 100% dodge chance you'd need 21700 dexterity! (50% Dodge at 10850 Dex - That's a lot of Paragon Levels)

At level 1, the relationship is:

> Dexterity / 2.2 = Dodge %, rounded to the nearest 0.x%

Here are a couple more levels:

```
Level 2: Dex/2.6
Level 3: Dex/3
Level 4: Dex/3.4
Level 5: ~ Dex/3.62
Level 6: ~ Dex/3.86
Level 7: ~ Dex/4.16
Level 9: ~ Dex/4.9
Level 11: ~ Dex/6.32
```

ETC.

The important one is level 70, because that's where you'll spend the most time.

Comment: This seems to agree with the other answer I got. X / 217 is the same as X * 0.00461.

Comment: Basically, yes. 1/217 isn't quite 0.00461, but since you're rounding the answer to the nearest 0.X%, they are essentially the same. I didn't really believe the other answer though, so I did my own research and found out that it varies by level. (I had over 100% dodge for my lower level Monk from Paragon levels and Hellfire ring)

Answer (score 0):

From the diablo 3 forums, this [post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12413371289) offers an equation but it doesn't look like anyone, but a thanks, confirmed it works. This is the most recent post providing a formula.

> For anyone interested / searching for this info:
>
> @Level 70: %Dodge = DEX * 0.00461
>
> This has been tested and is accurate from 217 up to 7000 dexterity.
>
> The % per dex lowers as you level up and I couldn't find the exact method the game uses to calculate this, but I was interested in the challenge of finding a useful equation that approximates it. It outputs accurate values at level 70, but is less accurate at lower levels ( off by ~ 0.1% at level 15 :P ).
>
> %Dodge = DEX / (0.00031*LVL^3 + 0.0186*LVL^2 + 0.25*LVL + 1.93)

Comment: Your two formulas result in different numbers. If I have 3000 dex, the first forumla gives me 13.83% dodge, whereas the second gives me 29.11% dodge, a very different number. Which one is it?

Comment: The first one is more current, I'll change my answer to reflect that fact. I provided the second one as another attempt to get the formula. There's not much to find on that sadly.

Answer (score -2):

The above is somewhat correct but not entirely. There are diminishing returns on this...In other words at lower dex values you will see a higher % of dodge per point. This is because a fixed ratio would allow for 100% dodge which of course will be silly (but cool). At 874 dexterity I have at 27.5% chance to dodge. That makes it 0.03146 and some change. So I basically get 3% per 100 points in dex...But again it's not fixed so by the time I do get another 100 points the value will decrease per point to more like 2.8% or something like that. The above, accepted, answer is in the right direction but the values are not completely accurate. Do not base your character build off those values. Those values would mean that I should only have a 17.48% chance to dodge...That's 10% off!

Comment: You completely failed to understand the math in Oak's answer. According to his math, 874 Dexterity would amount to 27.48% chance to dodge, which exactly correlates to what you said.