# Does dodge dodge everything?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Dodge work exactly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67147/how-does-dodge-work-exactly)

Is it possible to dodge any kind of attack with the dodge stat.

For example: could i dodge fire or plague or boss specific skills like the gas cloud from gom or diablo's grab attack.

Comment: Hello @TheJAVANoob, and welcome to Arqade!  It's a little difficult to understand what you're asking here (although I gather it's what attacks can and cannot be dodged). Please take a moment to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Not going to cite a source, so not an answer, but based on personal experience, I would say with 100% certainty that Dodge Does NOT dodge all attacks (making it an inferior form of damage mitigation when compared to Armor or All Resists).  I would say with confidence that you have 0% chance to dodge any "ground based attack" such as Desecrator or Plague from elite/rare monsters.  Hope that helps a little.